# Не убирается полоса прокрутки в select. Как быть?

Tags: html, css

Ничего не помогает. overflow: hidden !important; ставил, но не срабатывает. Почему так может быть?

Делаю здесь - http://ravlex.pluton-host.ru/polar/catalog.html В фильтре выпадающий список...

Comment: Стоит добавить скриншот, на котором продемонстрирована проблема.